# elsearticle hyperref incomatibility; avoid double Appendix as in "Appendix Appendix A"

Tags: hyperref

I get "foo Appendix Appendix A" instead of "foo Appendix A".

I have the suspicion that [elsearticle](https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle.dtx) containing "\def\appendixname{Appendix }" may result in the problem.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

foo \autoref{section:Test}

\appendix

\section{Test}
\label{section:Test}

\end{document}
```

Any idea on what to do?
(`\ref{section:Test}` works but I would like to still use autoref)

Comment: It is probably because `elsarticle` redefines `\thesection` as `\gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}` at `\appendix`. `\appendixname` does not really belong as a part of `\thesection`

Comment: Try with `\renewcommand\appendixautorefname[1]{}` (the argument is there to get rid of the fix space hyperref would insert).

Comment: Thanks! `\renewcommand\appendixautorefname[1]{}` solved it for me.